# how to test Onesignal push notifications on localhost?

Tags: push-notification, localhost, onesignal

I want to test OneSignal push notifications on localhost before I deploy my app to a remote server.

I followed the instructions provided by the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-http). When I enter `http://localhost` as the site url I get an error message that says:

> localhost is already taken. Please enter a different name.

Is there a way to use *OneSignal* on localhost ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `https://localhost` not `http://localhost`. OneSignal treats `localhost` as secure connections.

Comment: This may not be related, but I assume you got localhost working. Did you get the same issue like I get here: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/281. If yes, how do you solved it?

Comment: sorry @StefanN. I got localhost working but I didn't get your an issue similar to your one .. I followed the official docs and it was fine

Comment: It's not working form me, my url is: `localhost:3000` (react)

Answer (score 3):

Besides configuring OneSignal via dashboard, your `OneSignal.init` in your browser call must have the `allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin` option:

```
OneSignal.init({
  allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
  ...
})
```

More at https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-setup-faq#section-how-do-i-test-my-site-on-a-local-environment

Answer (score 1):

read in this doc https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-setup-faq#section-how-do-i-test-my-site-on-a-local-environment- and localhost must run in port 8000

Answer (score 1):

You may use Postman.
Just follow this steps, found at: [One Signal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/using-postman)

- Select POST and use url https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
- Set headers, like this: 
  [image]
- And, finally, add the push body 
  [image]

Surprisingly, simple. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, the answer is to add 'http://localhost' but when the configurator comes back with a message similar to 'localhost is already taken. Please enter a different name.' jut scroll down and type in a different subdomain. It's not very intuitive but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test onesignal push notifications over localhost, you should enable https://localhost on your test environment.
The following great post help me to setup it on macos, but I think you could implement it in other operative systems:

https://medium.com/@jonsamp/how-to-set-up-https-on-localhost-for-macos-b597bcf935ee

When you are able to start your web server at https://localhost:8080 , you should configure on OneSignal App  the following:

```
Site Url :  https://localhost:8080
Check "My site not fully HTTPS"
CHOOSE A LABEL :  your-test-env.OS.TC
```

By completing the setup suggested by Onesignal documentation, you will be able to test push notifications on your test environment.